# AppleScript executed with NSAppleScript does not work

Tags: macos, applescript, nsapplescript

I call and execute apple script in main thead below

```
NSAppleScript *as = [[NSAppleScript alloc]
initWithSource:@"tell application \"Finder\" to sleep"];
[as executeAndReturnError: NULL];
[as release];
```

but does not work, while the script

```
tell application Finder to sleep
```

works well in AppleScript Editor.

your comment welcome

Comment: It doesn't work? What happens?

Comment: This probably won't solve your problem, but it's worth noting that using the `"System Events"` context is the better choice - `"Finder"`'s `sleep` command is in the `Legacy` suite. Also, I assume you meant to double-quote `Finder` in your 2nd snippet.

Comment: if use "System Events", I can not find the suitable com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events

Answer (score 4):

This is the way to examine the result and error from [`-executeAndReturnError:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsapplescript_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAppleScript/executeAndReturnError%3a)

```
NSDictionary *errors = nil;
NSAppleEventDescriptor *result = [as executeAndReturnError:&errors];
NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
NSLog(@"errors: %@", errors);
```

Comment: it reports myapp[1595:303] result: <NSAppleEventDescriptor: null()>
 myapp[1595:303] errors: (null)

Comment: On my machine, that code works – puts my computer right to sleep.

Comment: if submit the app to mac store, does it need to set com.apple.security.scripting-targets or com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events?